# Django Database Routers

Tags: django

I have set up routers in my Django project, but the tables do not seem to be populating in any of the databases. Each time I run `python manage.py makemigrations HealthcareProject4` I can see that the migration file is being created successfully. However when I run `python manage.py migrate --database=default` nothing appears to populate in any of the databases I have set up.

**db_routers.py**

```
from HealthcareProject4.settings import DATABASE_ROUTERS
from HealthcareProject4.Conditions.models import *

class AuthRouter:
    route_app_labels = ['auth', 'contenttypes', 'admin',]
    
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == app_label
        return None

class EducationRouter:
    route_app_labels = ['EducationProject']
    
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == app_label
        return None

class HealthcareRouter:
    route_app_labels = ['HealthcareProject4']
    
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == app_label
        return None

class UsersRouter:
    route_app_labels = ['Users2']
    
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return model._meta.app_label
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == model._meta.app_label
        return None
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_Healthcare4',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'crm': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_CRM',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'education': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_Education',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'finance': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_Finance',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'legals': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_Legals',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'machinelearning': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_MachineLearning',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'media': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_Media',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'music': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_Music',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'socialservices': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_SocialServices',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'users': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_Users',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    'auth': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'NKFSLTD_Auth',
        'USER': 'Nf00038',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.116',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
                    }
                },
    }

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['Routers.db_routers.AuthRouter', 'Routers.db_routers.EducationRouter', 'Routers.db_routers.HealthcareRouter',]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class TestModel(models.Model):
    Test = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'EducationProject'
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods of the router `db_for_read` and `db_for_write` must return the name of the database that will be used and not the app label. You must return a key used in the `DATABASES` dict (one of the following: `default`, `crm`, `education`, `finance`, `legals`, `machinelearning`, `media`, `music`, `socialservices`, `users`, `auth`). The same applies for the method `allow_migrate`, you must compare `db` with the database name and not the app label. So for example:

```py
class EducationRouter:
    route_app_labels = ['EducationProject']
    
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'education'  # Here
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'education'  # Here
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'education'  # Here
        return None
```

Then run the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: OK, great, thank you for confirming. Also, please could you advise as to why everything migrates regardless of the database I choose to run a migrate on?

Comment: @NeilFaulkner When you run `migrate` you must specify the `--database DATABASE` option. Then Django checks your routers to know which migrations to apply to that database. If you don't specify a database the default database is used. If you start with fresh databases, only models handled by the given database (based on routers and apps) are migrated. In all your routers, you replaced `'education'` in the three methods I changed in my code with the correct database name (especially in `allow_migrate`)?